# Why do sometimes informations not are gathering using puppeter?

Tags: puppeteer

I'm using puppeter for gathering information and something one of these informations cames `[]`. This is an example of how I'm calling the functions of puppeter

```
try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
      ],
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitForSelector('div#results');
    await page.waitForSelector('h6.bestPrice');
    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
      let items = document.querySelectorAll('maintable > tbody > tr.productsName > td > div.products');

      if (items.length !== 0) {
        let data = [];

        items.forEach(function (el) {
          let object = null;
          el.querySelectorAll('h5 a').forEach(function (el) {
            object = { product: el.innerHTML, img: [] };
          });
          el.querySelectorAll('p a').forEach(function (el) {
            object.description = el.innerHTML;
          });
          el.querySelectorAll('h6.bestPriceText').forEach(function (el) {
            object.price = el.innerHTML;
          });
          el.querySelectorAll('div.slide a.fancybox-thumbs img').forEach(function (el) {
            object.img.push(el.getAttribute('src'));
          });
          data.push(object);
        });
        return data;
      }

      let error = null;
      document.querySelectorAll('div.noResults div.info-message h2').forEach(function (el) {
        error = ({ message: el.innerHTML });
      });
      return error;
    });
    await browser.close();
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    return { message: `Problems loading the page! Please, try again.${error}` };
  }
};
```

The information which something comes empty is `price`, sorry but I can't reveal the url, but I would like to know if exists any problem with this design code.

Comment: I'm sorry, but without the URL you're scraping, it's difficult (impossible?) to help. My recommendation is to make a [mcve] using a snippet of the markup that reproduces the problem. You can obfuscate irrelevant information you want to protect, like text contents and so forth.

Comment: Sorry, I understand, but the URL is part of that I need to protect, I pictured ẃhich was common problem maybe, based on the flux

Answer (score 0):

A Friend suggest me to add a timeout, because it could be a problem with rendering

```
 const resultado = await page.evaluate(async () => {
      const timeout = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
      await timeout(5000);
```